# Ansible: include group vars .yml file from command line

Tags: bash, ansible

Our vendor sends us Ansible playbooks and scripts for deployment. I need to check availability of some IP for ansible inventory groups, like:
`ansible mgm -i inventories/vrxinventory -m shell -a 'ping http://10.33.63.66/vrx/' -u user -k -v`. 
The destination is changing depending on the environment. Those destination IPs to ping are in group vars .yml file.

Is it possible to use variables from this group_var.yml file, through command line like:
`ansible mgm -i inventories/vrxinventory -m shell -a "ping {{ vrm_repo_url }}" -u user -k -v` ?

I really don't want to mess with their playbooks modification using sed/awk, during CI.

Comment: Never saw a `ping http://10.33.63.66/vrx/` command - how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use variables from this group_var.yml file, through command line like: `ansible mgm -i inventories/vrxinventory -m shell -a "ping {{ vrm_repo_url }}" -u user -k -v`

1. Yes, group variables will be read by `ansible` command for ad-hoc commands.
2. No, it makes no sense to execute `ping {{ vrm_repo_url }}` through `shell` module in Ansible:

   - firstly, because by default `ping` runs infinitely (this can be mitigated with parameters);
   - secondly, because you won't see any output of the `ping` command.

---

What you most likely want is to use:

- a [`wait_for` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/wait_for_module.html) with low `connect_timeout` parameter to check the connectivity between the target and some other machine;
- or a [`get_url` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/get_url_module.html) (as you seemingly want to check availability of web services).

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how to use variables from yml file during ad-hoc command?

Comment: Replace `ping {{ vrm_repo_url }}` with `echo {{ vrm_repo_url }} > /tmp/result.txt` and check the contents of the file. You should get the values defined in group vars, just like if you were using them in a playbook.

Comment: I mean, how to use this `group_var` yml file, during ad-hoc command execution? In your example, you just already use a variable, but which `ansible` commands flags I need to use to attach this variable file?

Comment: No, you never “attach” group vars — they are read automatically — no matter if you use `ansible-playbook` or ad-hoc `Ansible`. That’s what makes them group vars.